# How to get an specific located text into a dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with some text indexes which contains a necessary information that I want to copy into a list.

I don't know how is the text info specifically (the word always changes), but I know where is located in the index:

*'point.subclase.optimum.**R31**.done'*. R31 is the value which I would like to write in a list, so I know that that text, that is always different, is between ***point.subclase.optimum.*** and ***.done***.

I've tried with:

```
info_list = []
for col in df.columns:
    if ('point.subclase.optimum.' in col) and ('.done' in col):
        info_list.append(col)
```

But that script just provide me the entire index in the list.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with escape `\.` because special regex character, then remove possible missing values if no match by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and last convert output to list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(3)}, index=['point.subclase.optimum.R31.done',
                                         'point.subclase',
                                         'point.subclase.optimum.R98.done'])
print (df)
                                 a
point.subclase.optimum.R31.done  0
point.subclase                   1
point.subclase.optimum.R98.done  2

L = (df.index.str.extract(r'point\.subclase\.optimum\.(.*)\.done', expand=False)
             .dropna()
             .tolist())
print (L)
['R31', 'R98']
```

Comment: @Sergio - Solution above not working with new data?